# Force update of Formula with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that relies on data being pulled in from another sheet. The only issue is its taking a while (10s or so) for any updates to push across. I'm using a  `QUERY` in conjunction with `IMPORTRANGE` for this.

Without rewriting the code so that GAS deals with the import and SQL, is there anyway to force the sheet to update, equivalent to deleting the formula in the cell and then undoing? I've tried writing a bit of code to do it:

```
var sqlCell = ss.getSheetByName("LOOKUP").getRange("L4");
var sqlCellFormula = sqlCell.getFormula();
sqlCell.setFormula("");
sqlCell.setFormula(sqlCellFormula);
Utilities.sleep(1000);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

But that doesn't work at all for some reason. The `SLEEP` and `FLUSH` were just desperation!

Any help as ever gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

## variable ss is not defined

Try this:

```
function sqlcell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sqlCell = ss.getSheetByName("LOOKUP").getRange("L4");
  var sqlCellFormula = sqlCell.getFormula();
  sqlCell.setFormula("");
  sqlCell.setFormula(sqlCellFormula);
}
```

I investigated this a bit and decided to put this formula in L4: `=sum(A1:A20)`
And in A2: I put =A1 + 1 and copied that down A20 and then in the function I add one to A1 each time it runs.

```
function sqlTest() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('LOOKUP');
  var rg=sh.getRange("L4");
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(sh.getRange('A1').getValue()+1);
  //var sqlCellFormula = '=sum(A1:A20)';
  var sqlCellFormula = rg.getFormula();
  var T1=rg.getFormula();
  rg.setFormula("");
  var T2=rg.getFormula();
  rg.setFormula(sqlCellFormula);
  var T3=rg.getFormula();
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString('<br />T1: %s<br />T2: %s<br />T3: %s',T1,T2,T3 ));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'getFormula()')
  var end="is near";
}
```

At first I was get '#REF' errors at T1 but then reset A1 back to 1 and for some unknown reason it started working as expected.  I don't know why.  But this allows the data to change a little every time to see if the formula is still working.

So sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: That's my bad. It's higher up in the code and I just forgot to copy it. The code runs ok but just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Isn't it designed not do anything.  It deletes a formula and then puts it back the way it was.  In that case not doing anything is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: But I've played around with it a bit and sometime the getFormula() doesn't seem to work correctly.  It seems to mess up the range.